# Regular Expression and sed command: echo 1234567890|sed 's/((?<=\d)\d{3})*\b/TEST/'

Tags: regex, linux, sed

source is `1234567890`,  the regular expression `((?<=\d)\d{3})*\b` can match: `234567890`, so i think `sed` should replace `234567890` with `TEST`, but the result is: `1234567890`, why?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

look-behind is not supported by sed. 
you could try ssed (super sed), it supports perl mode, (-R) then you could pass perl style regex to it. e.g. look ahead/behind.

see the feature list:

https://launchpad.net/ssed

Comment: I think the latest version of GNU sed supports -R as well. See here: http://sed.sourceforge.net

Answer (score 0):

You need to rewrite the regex without lookbehind:

```
s/(\d)(?:\d{3})*\b/\1TEST
```